# Total degree and highest degree of polynomial set

Tags: functions, polynomials

Could anybody tell me how to calculate the highest degree of a polynomial set?

For example (three variables),

$x^2+y^3+z^3y^3=a$

$x+z^2+x^2+y=b$

$x^2+y+z^3=c$

There is a mathematical name for the highest degree boundary that I forgot. If you can remember the name, that would be fantastic. Thank you very much.